# Ocaml. Core module in OcaIDE eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ocaml

I started programming with Ocaml few days ago. 
I use eclipse OcaIDE, ubuntu.

When I try to use the Core module in a code :
  open Core.Std
  ...

I get an error:
Error: Unbound module Unix

I tried to create .ocamlinit file with adds:

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
```

The same error occurs in eclipse.
Сode without the use of the modules run fine.

Please, tell me, what I have to do?

Sorry for bad english.
Thank You for your answers!

Comment: You can try to add `#require "unix"` as the error mentionned.

Comment: `.ocamlinit` has no connection with OCaIDE in particular and ocaml compiler in general. So it will not help. One need to go to the project configuration in OCaIDE and add corresponding compiler flags, like `-I`, and enumerate the required `cmxa` and `cma` file. That's why I discourage OP from using OCaIDE, it can be used, but requires some sort of expertise in OCaml infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

OCaIDE is not wide-spread in OCaml community, so it is not well supported. Try to use emacs or vim. If you insist on using OCaIDE, then a good place to start is to view [tutorials](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/tutorials/3-projects/projects.htm).

P.S. Even if you manage to configure OCaIDE it will be still much worse than Emacs+[Merlin](https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin).

Comment: I used for your advice Emacs. Remove and install ocaml, core and  lwt. There are no .ocamlinit file now. But in Emacs and in terminal : 
open Core.Std;;   ->  Error: Unbound module Core
open Lwt;;   ->  Error: Unbound module Lwt

Comment: short answer: use `corebuild` to compile your programs, e.g., `corebuild -pkg lwt myprog.native` (under assumption that your code is in `myprog.ml`). Use `coretop` for interactive toplevel. Link `lwt` library into the toplevel with `#require "lwt"`. And there no need to delete `.ocamlinit`, it is loaded on start of the interactive toplevel.

Comment: `root@genesis:/home/kirill/workspace/Test2# opam install core

[WARNING] Running as root is not recommended

[NOTE] Package core is already installed (current version is 112.35.01).

root@genesis:/home/kirill/workspace/Test2# corebuild hw.native

corebuild: command not found`

cannot use corebuild(((

Comment: have you ran `eval $(opam config env)`?

Comment: 'eval $(opam config env)
corebuild hw.native' - it works!

Thank You very match!